# Object rotation with damping jumps on full circle

Tags: algorithm, animation

The equation is simple:

```
rotation += deltaRotation / SPEED
```

This way we have nice decelerating rotation motion. However problem arises we reach the gap between Math.PI and -Math.PI - see snippet for jerky motion example.

```js
const SPEED = 0.05;
let div = document.querySelector('div');
let targetRotation = 0;
let rotation = 0;

function rotate(dt) {
  let deltaRotation = targetRotation - rotation;
  rotation += deltaRotation * SPEED;

  div.style.transform = 'rotate(' + rotation + 'deg)';

  requestAnimationFrame(rotate);
}

document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
  targetRotation = Math.atan2(e.y - 150, e.x - 150) * 180 / Math.PI;
}, false);

requestAnimationFrame(rotate);
```

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #BADA55, red);
  transform: rotate(0);
  margin: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

What can be done to prevent such behaviour?

Comment: Can you perhaps [simplify your question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to illustrate the problem more clearly? Also, why are you using `let` instead of `var`?

Comment: @squeamishossifrage: That's ES6, and doesn't matter as my problem is in different language (unless it doesn't work in SO major browsers, but I guess we're all devs here using latest versions). What would you do to simplify this? Clearly object doesn't rotate smoothly around full circle

Comment: In Chrome, your snippet doesn't do anything interesting at all. It probably won't work in Firefox either. And isn't the solution to your problem simply to adjust the value of `targetRotation` by adding or subtracting 2π so that the absolute value of `targetRotation - rotation` is always less than π?

Comment: @squeamishossifrage I simply cannot believe this, but that's exactly what worked. I tried for hours, and it didn't. I think I missed the modulo step. Huh, such is life. Please add this as an answer so I can accept (add this as a snippet for other people) https://jsfiddle.net/yk6h4074/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is adjust the value of `targetRotation` by adding or subtracting 2π so that the absolute value of `targetRotation - rotation` is always less than π:

```
if (Math.abs(deltaRotation) > Math.PI) {
  deltaRotation -= 2 * Math.PI * Math.sign(deltaRotation);
}
```

Here's a modified snippet showing how it works. (I've replaced `let` with `var` to support Chrome and Firefox browsers.)

```js
const SPEED = 0.05;
var div = document.querySelector('div');
var targetRotation = Math.PI - 0.1;
var rotation = 0;

function rotate(dt) {
  var deltaRotation = (targetRotation - rotation) % (Math.PI * 2);
  if (Math.abs(deltaRotation) > Math.PI) {
    deltaRotation -= 2 * Math.PI * Math.sign(deltaRotation);
  }
  rotation += deltaRotation * SPEED;
  div.style.transform = 'rotate(' + rotation + 'rad)';
  requestAnimationFrame(rotate);
}

document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
  targetRotation = Math.atan2(e.y - 65, e.x - 100);
}, false);

requestAnimationFrame(rotate);
```

```css
div {
  width: 30px;
  height: 100px;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #BADA55, red);
  transform: rotate(0);
  margin: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: You forgot to change
`var deltaRotation = targetRotation - rotation;`
to `var deltaRotation = (targetRotation - rotation) % (Math.PI * 2);` Otherwise it's all jittery

Comment: @Misiur Sorry, fixed that now